# String command does not run by SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I want to code an optional SQL command where any parameters that is null does not taken. For example if `M_SYSCODE` is -1 the select query does not filter data according to `M_SYSCODE`.

This is my code:

```cs
int m_syscode = 1;//-1 for false
string m_code = null;//null for false
string m_name = null;
string m_shortname = null;
string parentcode = null;
int m_abstract = -1;
string category = null;
int is_active = -1;

string sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE ";
int length = sql.Length;
string andCondition = "AND ";
bool flag = false;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

if (m_syscode != -1)
{
    sql += $"M_SYSCODE={m_syscode} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@m_syscode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = m_syscode;
    flag = true;
}

if(m_code != null)
{
    sql = flag ? sql+=andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_CODE={m_syscode} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@m_code", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = m_code;
    flag = true;
}

if (m_name != null)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_NAME={m_name} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@m_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = m_name;
    flag = true;
}

if (m_shortname != null)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_SHORTNAME={m_shortname} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@m_shortname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = m_shortname;
    flag = true;
}

if (parentcode != null)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_PARENTCODE={m_syscode} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@parentcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = parentcode;
    flag = true;
}

if (m_abstract != -1)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_ABSTRACTCODE={m_abstract} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@m_abstract", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = m_abstract;
    flag = true;
}

if (category != null)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"M_CATEGORY={category} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@category", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = category;
    flag = true;
}

if (is_active != -1)
{
    sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
    sql += $"IS_ACTIVE={is_active} ";
    command.Parameters.Add("@is_active", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = is_active;
    flag = true;
}

sql += ";";
//return sql;

string statement = sql.Length == length ? null : sql;

//string sql = $"SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE M_SYSCODE={m_syscode} ";

//SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

//command.Parameters.Add("@m_syscode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = m_syscode;

if (statement == null) 
     return null;

SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();

if (result.Read())
{ 
     return result[1].ToString(); 
}

result.Close();
return null; // return M_CODE
```

I printed the output and the query is correct, but when I execute it, I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'.

How can I fix it?

Also here is a correct query that my code created:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE M_SYSCODE = 1 ;
```

Comment: "I printed output and the query is correct " Apparently not, since you get a syntax error. If you could [edit] your question to include that printed output, that would probably help a lot.

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use SQL in strings and concatenation and it is subject to SQL injection. Try and use an ORM like the Entity Framework or NHibernate. You get typed classes and can use LINQ to query the database.

Comment: I know that but this is a homework and i have to do it like that.@PaulSinnema

Comment: i added it. @ZoharPeled

Comment: So.... why bother adding parameters if you're not using them?

Comment: This function is used by frontend and there is only one submitted form and that page contains some parameters. If the area in the form  does not be filled then it return null and i want to handle with it. @ZoharPeled

Comment: No, I mean that `sql += $"M_SYSCODE={m_syscode} ";` should be `sql += $"M_SYSCODE=@m_syscode ";`...

Comment: Changed it but still same. @ZoharPeled

Comment: So now you get `SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE M_SYSCODE = @m_syscode ;` and it's still a syntax error?

Comment: I solved the problem you can see below. @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 0):

I have to add SqlCommand command after the last change in my sql string. I cannot change parameters in every call.

The solution is here:

```
            connection.Open();
            //string sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT " +
            //    "(M_SYSCODE, M_CODE, M_NAME, M_SHORTNAME, M_PARENTCODE, M_ABSTRACT, M_CATEGORY, IS_ACTIVE) " +
            //    "VALUES("+M_SYSCODE.ToString()+
            //    ","+M_CODE+","+M_NAME+ "," + M_SHORTNAME + "," + M_PARENTCODE + "," + M_ABSTRACT.ToString() + "," 
            //    + M_CATEGORY + "," + IS_ACTIVE.ToString()+ ")";


            int m_syscode = 1;//-1 for false
            string m_code = null;//null for false
            string m_name = null;
            string m_shortname = null;
            string parentcode = null;
            int m_abstract = -1;
            string category = null;
            int is_active = -1;

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE ";
            int length = sql.Length;
            string andCondition = "AND ";
            bool flag = false;
            
            
            if (m_syscode != -1)
            {
                sql += $"M_SYSCODE=@m_syscode ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@m_syscode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = m_syscode;
                flag = true;
            }
            if(m_code != null)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql+=andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_CODE=@m_code ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@m_code", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = m_code;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (m_name != null)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_NAME=@m_name ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@m_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = m_name;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (m_shortname != null)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_SHORTNAME=@m_shortname ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@m_shortname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = m_shortname;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (parentcode != null)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_PARENTCODE=@parentcode ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@parentcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = parentcode;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (m_abstract != -1)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_ABSTRACTCODE=@m_abstract ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@m_abstract", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = m_abstract;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (category != null)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"M_CATEGORY=@category ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@category", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = category;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (is_active != -1)
            {
                sql = flag ? sql += andCondition : sql;
                sql += $"IS_ACTIVE=@is_active ";
                //command.Parameters.Add("@is_active", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = is_active;
                flag = true;
            }
            sql=sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
            sql += ";";
            //return sql;

            string statement = sql.Length == length ? null : sql;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            if (m_syscode != -1)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@m_syscode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = m_syscode;
            }
            if (m_code != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@m_code", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = m_code;
            }
            if (m_name != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@m_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = m_name;
            }
            if (m_shortname != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@m_shortname", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = m_shortname;
            }
            if (parentcode != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@parentcode", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = parentcode;
            }
            if (m_abstract != -1)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@m_abstract", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = m_abstract;
            }
            if (category != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@category", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = category;
            }
            if (is_active != -1)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@is_active", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = is_active;

            }









            //string sql = $"SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE M_SYSCODE={m_syscode} ";


            //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

            //command.Parameters.Add("@m_syscode", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = m_syscode;

            if (statement == null) return null;
            SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (result.Read()) { return result[1].ToString(); }

            result.Close();
            return null; // return M_CODE
```